# Find the frequency of random numbers in array

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a simple code in C which creates 30 random numbers, and counts how often these appear in an array.

But I have the problem that when I print the times they appear, they repeat:

```
-- 5 -- 2 -- 5 --

The number 5 is repeated 2 twice

The number 2 is repeated 1 twice

The number 5 is repeated 1 twice
```

But I need something like this:

```
-- 5 -- 2 -- 5 --

The number 5 is repeated 2 twice

The number 2 is repeated 1 twice
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   srand(time(NULL));
   int vector[30], i, j, frecuencia[30];

   for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
   {
       int numeroAleatorio = rand() % 50;
       vector[i] = numeroAleatorio;
       printf(" -- %d", vector[i]);

   }

   printf("\n-------------------------------------\n");

   for (i = 0; i < 30; i++)
   {
       frecuencia[i] = 1;
       for (j = i+1; j < 30; j++)
       {
           if (vector[i] == vector[j])
           {
               frecuencia[i]++;
           }
       }

       printf("El numero %d se repite %d veces \n", vector[i], frecuencia[i]);
   }

   return (0);
}
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to set the array `frecuencia` to zeros

Comment: Have you tried running your code in a debugger, and observing what it does?

Comment: `vector` is not a very good name for the array, as it is a commonly used standard template in c++

Comment: Consider: `for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) frequencia[vector[i]]++;` (You'd still need to initialize `frequencia[]`, and you need to add checks that you don't write out of bounds.)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is your array can contain more than one occurrence of a number (that's why you are counting their frequency. Yet you are printing the message for each element in `vector`. So it shouldn't come as a surprise that if vector contains a number more than once, you would get as many messages for that number.

Either you'd need to find a way to mark the elements you already counted (i.e. when `vector[i] == vector[j]`, you shouldn't count frequencies for `vector[j]` when i becomes equal to j later in the outer loop.

Otherwise, you should split what you are trying to do into two separate steps. First go through the array, compute & collect the frequences. Then go through the frequency array and print them.

The second way is probably simpler to go with.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring every index in each loop is not a good approach. Instead, consider declaring the whole array as zeroes:

```
int frecuencia[30] = {0};
```

The problem you are facing is because your code looks only forward and never backwards. In that case, when you have more than one 5's, your code looks at the first five then counts all the appearances of 5.

When it comes to the second 5, your code again looks at all the 5's that is **after** that index because you didnt remove the appearances of all 5's.

To remedy that, you can approach it two ways

1- Get rid of all the appearances of the looked number by a number that will never appear in your array

(Let's consider -1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
   if(vector[i] == -1){
      continue; //We don't have to search for the negative number.
   }
   for (j = i+1; j < 30; j++)
   {
       if (vector[i] == vector[j])
       {
           frecuencia[i]++;
           vector[j] = -1; //Here we set the counted appearance of that number to -1
           //So it never gets counted again.
       }
   }

   printf("El numero %d se repite %d veces \n", vector[i], frecuencia[i]);
}
```

2- Depending on the range of your numbers, have the *range* as your array size

(Number range is 50)

```
int frecuencia[50] = {0};
```

This way, we will insert the frequency of number n at the index n.

```
for (i = 0; i < 30; i++){
   frecuencia[vector[i]]++;
}

for(i = 0; i < 30; i++){
   printf("El numero %d se repite %d veces \n", vector[i], frecuencia[i]);
}
```

Comment: Good! I can see that the second option is much easier to interpret. It even seems to have fewer lines of code! Without your help I wouldn't have gotten the solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you. You can first create a list with length of the random numbers lenght. in this case it is 50. for example the frequency of 8 will be stored in freq[8] and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
        int freq[50] = {0};//frequencies
        int vector[30];//random numbers
        srand(time(NULL));
        for(int i = 0;i < 30;i++){
                vector[i] = rand()%50;
        }
        //lets count them to frequencies first
        for(int i = 0;i < 30;i++){
                freq[vector[i]]++;
        }
        //then we can print them
        for(int i = 0;i < 50;i++){
                if(freq[i] > 0){
                        printf("The number %d repeated %d times\n",i,freq[i]);
                }
        }
}
```

this works fine. Ask me anything about this code if you need to ask. And experienced coders please let me know if you can see any flaw on my code. I can edit than.

Comment: Make life easier `int *freq = calloc(50,sizeof(int));//frequencies` -. `int[50] = {0};`

Comment: I like the way you solved it!

I wouldn't have thought of doing it that way, I'm just learning how to program.
I understand most of the code, and I've already tried it and it works. 
What I don't understand is why `freq[50] = {0}`  with another number or without the {0} doesn't work

Comment: @TordyCapz Firstly thank you for your comment. When we not initialize the integers in freq array there will be random numbers like 19872364, 81723382 ect. which is known as UB (Undefined Behavior). And when you initialized some different number than 0 the frequencies will start to counting from that number. If you are new at c i recommend you to read about Undefined Behaviors in c. It could help you to have better understanding of c.

Comment: @baran-sahİn Oh! Thanks! i see how works... So also in `vector[30]` you should also add the `={0}` ?  
Since later they will be filled with random numbers

Comment: Actually it is not necessary at vector array because even if it has some weird values at the beginning it will filled with our random values. In freq array we are adding up to existing values so we need to initialize it to 0. But it is not the case in vector array because we are not using existing value. So it is not necessary if the value is initially something like 175732875.

Comment: I am not experienced enough to know this but even if it is not necessary I think initializing to zero is good way to program so don't be afraid of using it. It won't cause any Undefined Behavior or some sort of problem.